# put XML file into InputStream

Tags: java, xml, io

I would like to put http://www.nasa.gov/rss/dyn/image_of_the_day.rss into a FileInputStream any suggestions how can I do that.

Comment: To use a `FileInputStream`, you'll have to have a local file. For *any* `InputStream`, you can use `URLConnection.getInputStream`.

Comment: @Sunny <waves hand>This is not the input stream you are looking for</waves hand>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't read from that URL into a FileInputStream  because it's not a file. However, you can read into an InputStream:

```
InputStream input = new URL("http://www.nasa.gov/rss/dyn/image_of_the_day.rss").openStream();
```

Answer (score 1):

By using java.net.URL  construct new object like this.
URL url = new URL(" http://www.nasa.gov/rss/dyn/image_of_the_day.rss");
then simply call
url.openStream(); //this will return InputStream Object